# display:table width+padding gives scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I need to give padding to the parent div which has `display:table` but when it has `width:100%` then adding padding causes horizontal scroll bar so how to make the parent div full width to the browser with padding (but no scroll bar) ?

Here is my code

```
.tbl{
    display:table;
    width:100%; padding:10px;
    background:#C99 
}
.row{
    display:table-row;
    width:100%
}
.cell{
    display:table-cell;
    border:solid 1px black  
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MPfH3/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used to `box-sizing`

```
.tbl{
box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MPfH3/1/)**

More about **[box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)**

More About **[Box modules](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/)**

Comment: this is the Box Model you box width is width+ paddingLeft + PaddingRight + BorderLeft + BorderRight = Box Width ... http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/